# why there are two member functions?

Tags: c++, iostream, istream

I am learning c++, however, I can not understand what is the difference BTW:

```
std::cin.get();
```

and

```
std::cin.getline();
```

although;I know how to use each of them, but can't understand why there are two?
 I've read this explanation :

> `getline`reads the newline character then discard it; whereas `.get()`reads it then leaves it in the input queue ..!! why each of them does what it does ?

sorry for bad English :(

Comment: See [`std::istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) and [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) for clarification please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`std::cin.get()`, when called without parameters, reads one single character from input and returns it.

`std::cin.getline(char* str, std::streamsize count)` reads one line of input and copies it into the buffer `str`, followed by an extra null character to form a C-string. `count` must be the size of that buffer, i.e. the maximal number of characters (plus the null byte) it can copy into it.

To read a line without caring about the buffer size it may be better to use `std::getline`:

```
#include <string>
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Reads a line from `cin` into `line`.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream  and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline .

Comment: `get` has an overload that reads to a line terminator. I guess that's what OP is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

"get" only retrieves a character, "getline" gets all characters to a line terminator. Thats the main difference.

Comment: `get` has an overload that reads to a line terminator. I guess that's what OP is asking about.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about [#4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) vs. [#2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).